# How to NOT sort the datatable using DataTable.Select() in C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I form a DataTable from database where all the records are in the required order. DataTable is formed correctly. Then I try to get specific records from DataTable with:

```
Records.Select(String.Format("Car = '{0}' AND Time <> '00:59:00.00'", car)); // Records = DataTable
```

Somehow it gets sorted by car name which I don't want to, I just want to grab it like it is. No sorting for the table has been made in any way anywhere in the application.

I also have tried Select(); with sort 'null', nothing has changed.

Have you got any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Sorry, I've made a mistake. The query is:

```
Records.Select(String.Format("Track = '{0}' AND Time <> '00:59:00.00'", trackname)); // Records = DataTable
```

DataTable has columns: ID, PlayerID, Track, Car, Time. Somehow the results are sorted by Car which is not even in the query.

Comment: if you run the equivalent SQL query on you database, what order does the data some out in?

Comment: You would have to sort the results of the select statement.  This is working as intended the results is a subset of your data.

Comment: Matt, like 'what you see is what you get', i get results as it is sorted in the database.

Ramhound, in database cars are UF1, XRG, XFG, RB4 etc. As you see, sorting wouldn't work as there is no sequence of letters.

Answer (score 0):

Errr... I've found the way including the ID form database to the DataTable and sorting by ID...